# Use JSOM to retrieve id of newly inserted item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom

I am using JSOM and would like to retrieve the id of the newly inserted item.  I've tried a few things and nothing has worked.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Travel Request Memos');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Title field');
        oListItem.set_item('From', 'from field');
        oListItem.set_item('Subj', 'subject field');
        oListItem.set_item('To', 'to field');
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance1', guidance1);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance2', guidance2);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance3', guidance3);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance4', guidance4);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance5', guidance5);     

        oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddSucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddFailed)
    );
    //alert(oListItem.get_Id());   <-- caused an error
}

function onAddSucceeded(sender, args) {
    $("#divResult").html("Item successfully added!");
}
function onAddFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: `oListItem.get_Id();` will return the id of the newly created item, the problem is the variable `oListItem` is not accessible in the success function. Just declare the variable as global and it will work.

Comment: this still does not work for me! It keeps returning -1 even though the item IS being created - any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code. This works perfectly for me:

```
var oListItem;  //Declared this as a global variable So that it will be accessible in success function
function AddNewItem(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Travel Request Memos');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Title field');     
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddSucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddFailed));
}

function onAddSucceeded(sender, args) {
    var newItemId = oListItem.get_id();  //get Id of newly create item
    alert(newItemId);

}
function onAddFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: this works and should be the accepted answer